# How to eliminate "fontawesome5.sty not found" error?

Tags: packages, fontawesome

In this file, that I have attached, I can't compile the `.tex` file because "fontawesome5.sty not found." error.
link:
[download file here.](http://uploadboy.me/zitcs6g9fyjq/Tex.rar.html)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. Please add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/172164) of your code directly to the question, as a Code Sample. You can add the important parts of your log where the error is shown as well. Linking to files on other websites is not a good idea as it is much more hassle for someone trying to help you (and in the future the link might expire and the question becomes useless as a resource).

Comment: Missing file, probably a fontawesome5 package. Perhaps a typo (just fontawesome?), or you need to get the relevant package (or find one that gives equivalent functionality, if it isn't freely available and you need it for a document you can't adjust).